# XCode colors desaturating when compiled into Simulator

Tags: xcode, colors, simulator

The colors in my ViewControllers are all desaturating when I compile into the simulator. The same desaturation occurs when viewed on my iPhone. Within XCode itself, the colors appear fine, it's just compilation that appears to be the problem. I've been looking high and low for color settings but no luck. Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a bug in Xcode 7 Beta. I just upgraded and the issue was fixed.